# Jenkins environment variables from file for nodes group

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to set environment variables from a file to a group of nodes in Jenkins?

Let's say there are two groups: build nodes with the label `build` and test nodes with the label `test`. The idea is whenever a job is scheduled to `build` nodes, set the environment variables from file `build.properties` file and the same logic is for `test` nodes.

I found a plugin - [Environment Injector](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) that almost does what I need - it could inject environment variables from a file. But it does that on a single node level, while I need to be able to assign it on a node group level. Also, I'm not sure if the plugin could append values to the PATH variable using a file.

Answer (score 0):

Environment Injector should solve the issue.
to set the variables at the global level, which will apply to all nodes. make sure to Go to the `Manage Jenkins` page and click on the `Configure System` link. Scroll down to the `Global Properties` section and click the `Add` button next to the "Environment variables" field.

as they mentioned in there docs, it can set At node (controller and agent) level. At node (controller and agent) level.
https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/#plugin-content-at-node-controller-and-agent-level

when you add In the `Name` field, enter the name of the environment variable. In the `Value` field, enter the value for the variable. You can also use the `Properties File Path` field to specify a file that contains the environment variables you want to set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But how does it help to assign a variable to a group of nodes? It could do either to all nodes (global) or to singe (on single node level)

Comment: first you use the EnvInject plugin to set the variables at the global level, and then use node labels to apply the variables to the nodes that belong to the group. the trick here is using labels.

Comment: How do you mean? I added global env variables to the master. Let's say variable `ForTest` and 'ForBuild'. How should I use node labels to apply the variables to the nodes that belong to the specific group? I think I'm missing something here since I don't understand what the trick is..

Answer (score 0):

I can't find how to resolve it, but I found another way to deal with it.

I set environment variables from a file in all jobs; my page is Chinese, and I translated it manually; please refer to it.

first:Manage Jenkins-->Security-->Environment Injector Plugin-->Enable loading files from controller

then:in your job Configuration-->Prepare the operating environment-->Attribute file path  add your file path (in your jenkins server) then Select "load scripts and properties files from controller"